# Remover espaço padrão de container

Tags: html, css, div

Estou realizando uma modificação de estilo dentro da minha `#div1`, porém ela está dentro de um `container`, então por isso a estilização não pega o campo inteiro, é como se a `div` não ocupasse o campo inteiro, há margem esquerda e direita nas duas, tentei mexer nos `margin` e `padding`, mas sem sucesso. Segue foto ilustrativa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.borda{
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container borda col-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div  class="borda div1 pt-3  justify-content-start col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <input class="div1 form-control" type="text" placeholder="Nome" name="nome" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <input class="div1 form-control" type="text" placeholder="Profissão" name="profissao" required>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="redessociaisdiv" class="pt-3 justify-content-start col-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
  <form>
    <div class="pt-4 col-5 col-sm-5  d-inline-flex col-md-5 col-lg-5">
      <img src="img/facebookverde.png" width=40px; height=100%;>
    <div class="form-group">
       <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Facebook" name="facebook" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-5 col-sm-5 align-self-center d-inline-flex col-md-5 col-lg-5">
    <img src="img/instagramverde.png" width=40px; height=100%;>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Instagram" name="instagram" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Não existe nenhuma #div1 no seu código. Existe uma classe .div1

Answer (score 1):

No Bootstrap basta usar a classe `.no-gutters` no `container` ou `row`, ou então coloca `m-0` no elemento que quer tirar as margens, ou `p-0` onde quer tirar o padding.

Veja o que diz a documentação: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#no-gutters

> The gutters between columns in our predefined grid classes can be removed with `.no-gutters`. This removes the negative `margins` from `.row` and the horizontal `padding` from all immediate children columns.

Aqui um exemplo sugerido:

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">.col-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-6 col-md-4">.col-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

E aqui a definição do que seria o CSS do `no-gutters`

```
.no-gutters {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;

  > .col,
  > [class*="col-"] {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

É só você adicionar no CSS esse código.

```
.container {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Pois é a `<div>` com a classe `container` que tem o `padding` e não a `<div>` com classe `borda` vale lembrar que você está trabalhando com *bootstrap* então você está trabalhando com um código css já configurado por isso que estava acontecedo isso.

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style>

    .container {
      padding: 0;
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container borda col-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 d-flex justify-content-center border">
<div  class="borda div1 pt-3  justify-content-start col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-4">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <input class="div1 form-control" type="text" placeholder="Nome" name="nome" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <input class="div1 form-control" type="text" placeholder="Profissão" name="profissao" required>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="redessociaisdiv" class="pt-3 justify-content-start col-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
<form>
  <div class="pt-4 col-5 col-sm-5  d-inline-flex col-md-5 col-lg-5">
    <img src="img/facebookverde.png" width=40px; height=100%;>
  <div class="form-group">
     <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Facebook" name="facebook" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-5 col-sm-5 align-self-center d-inline-flex col-md-5 col-lg-5">
  <img src="img/instagramverde.png" width=40px; height=100%;>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Instagram" name="instagram" required>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```